# Refreshing data display on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, refresh

I have two fragments on a view pager. 
I once had to move data from fragment B to A and refresh the data displayed on A and I did it with getItemPosition.
For some reason, the same method doesn't work when I try to reset all data..

In my adapter i have :

```
public void refresh()
    {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition( Object obj ) 
    {
        return POSITION_NONE; 
    }
```

in fragment where I click 'reset' :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        notTriedPasswordsList = PagerActivity.mainList;
.....
....
    resetButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick( View v ) 
                    {
                        PagerActivity.resetPasswords();  
                        PagerActivity.viewPagerAdapter.refresh();
                    }});
```

viewPager activity hosting both fragments:

```
public static void resetPasswords()
    {
        mainList.addAll( 0, historyList );
        historyList.clear();
        PagerActivity.viewPagerAdapter.refresh();
    }
```

Main fragment where the pass is displayed :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

.....
        nextCodeDisplay = ( TextView ) view.findViewById( R.id.passwordDisplayTextView );
        nextCodeDisplay.setText( notTriedPasswordsList.get( 0 ).getPasswordString() );

....
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {          
                notTriedPasswordsList.remove( 0 );

                        if( notTriedPasswordsList.size() > 0  && !(notTriedPasswordsList.get( 0 ).getTried()) )
                        {
                            nextCodeDisplay.setText( notTriedPasswordsList.get( 0 ).getPasswordString() );
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: How is your progress? I notice you have not responded recently.

Comment: use interface for communication between two fragments, it will work in that way.....

Answer (score 2):

`PagerActivity` is treated like a static class, and you can only access static methods and member data and objects in this way. About code:

```
notTriedPasswordsList = PagerActivity.mainList;
```

Note: So now `PagerActivity` can access static `mainList` object, or `notTriedPasswordsList` (sharing the same memory). But this is the only object you can access since your code references static methods.

On code `PagerActivity.viewPagerAdapter.refresh()`, I am not clear on what data this refreshes since I don't see the enough code, again `refresh()` must be a static method. With code `notifyDataSetChanged`(), there must be a direct link between `viewPagerAdapter` and the data object, probably an **ArrayList**. Certainly I don't see any direct relation between the two.

Perhaps you want code like:

```
viewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new viewPagerAdapter();
```

This way you can have the relationship between the adapter and possibly an ArrayList object. The benefit of creating an instance with **new** is that it saves data and the state inside the class in the form of an object, in my sample that is `pagerAdapter`.

I could not suggest specific set of codes for now since I don't see sufficient amount of it for me to fix. Perhaps you can fix code first and then we all can contribute.

Comment: @BVtp, For clarity, I think you should post more relevant code related to the Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `PagerActivity.viewPagerAdapter.refresh();` won't cause your fragment to be redrawn. Instead you should access your fragment directly and create a custom `refreshUI()` method in it.

```
public void refreshUI(){
     nextCodeDisplay.setText( notTriedPasswordsList.get( 0 ).getPasswordString() );
}
```

Comment: can you even call clear on an adapter?
I'm getting an error.. `the method getAdapter() is undefined for the type ...`

Comment: What are mainList and historyList (ListView ? ArrayList?)? What do you mean by reset data ? clear the list only or clear and refill with default items ?

Comment: they're both array lists. By resetting I am deleting everything in historyList , and moving what was in there back to mainList which is what is displayed to the user.

Comment: Then your code seems to be only modifying data but never the UI. can you post the code where you display your password for the first time ?

Comment: I've edited the original post and added it there .
Thank you.

Comment: No man.. it just displays the first object in ArrayList and then stuck again..
By the way I already used somewhere here that `viewPagerAdapter.refresh()` method, and it works perfectly. I have no idea what's up with it now..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change your approach. I've uploaded a simple project to my [dropbox public folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13066693/TestPopupWindow.zip). Here you can find a reference implementation of how two fragments managed by a ViewPager can share information. The first Fragment - Fragment#1 - simply displays a String that is generated by Fragment#2. Fragment#2 has a button that, when clicked, sends a random String to Fragment#1 through the Activity. No need to refresh viewpager, no need of static methods, simple and working. I guess you can adapt this example to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want to refresh your data, personally i would like to suggest to use swipe refresh layout. It will be very useful for this purpose and stylish as well. Following is the code.

Swipe_Refresh_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >





        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:clickable="true"
             />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And following is the activity i am using for this layout.

```
public class LatestNewsFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener ,OnScrollListener{


    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        =
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Swipe_Refresh_layout, container, false);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
                android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 

                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                additemstatus();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Now in overridden refresh method you can refresh or load your data. I hope this will be very helpful for your support.